# How to find specific services using Docker Swarm on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-swarm, amazon-elb

Is there any way to do load balancing when deploying a series of microservices in AWS using Docker Swarm? 
Basically, I'd like to attach a specific service to an elastic load balancer the same way that can be done using ECS. Using ECS or EKS directly is not an option.

A way to do it would be by configuring the health check of the elastic load balancer to attack an endpoint only available in the service to find but for what I understand this would be inefficient as it would basically make the ELB keep making health check requests to endpoints that don't even exist in some EC2 instances.
Is there any other way of doing this?